# Time complexity of Integer.toBinaryString() in Java

Tags: java, performance, binary

I want to know the time complexity of Integer.toBinaryString().

Comment: Then look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l302) and figure it out.

Comment: Not sure what "time complexity" would mean  when the operand is at most four bytes.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The max value of `n` at above 4.2 *billion* (max unsigned `int`) is high enough for time complexity to be relevant. In this instance, since complexity is related to length of result, it's very small, but still, calculating Big-O for `n` values in the billions could have made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this:

- `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` produces a string of length `ceiling(log2(n))`.  That computation will take time that is roughly proportional to `log(n)`.
- The maximum value for `n` is 2^31 - 1, and that computation will always take less than some fixed constant time.

---

In fact, the question of the big O complexity of `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` is not mathematically meaningful.  By definition, big O complexity is about  a function's behavior as some variable tends to infinity.  And the only variable ( `n` ) cannot do that in this context.

Comment: Before anyone mentions it: my answer ignores the sign of `n`.  This is a simplifying assumption that makes no *practical* difference ...